# Error in R.java class

Tags: android, r.java-file

So I was happily coding away, and suddenly an error has appeared in my R.java class.
It's created a string, and says there is a "syntax error, and that I should delete the token 'sword'". I tried fixing it, but have instead created a duplicate string, "Long".

Here's the code:

```
public static final class string {
    public static final int Long=0x7f050001;
    public static final int Long Sword=0x7f050002;
    public static final int app_name=0x7f050000;
    public static final int desc=0x7f050003;
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this error? Also, R.java doesn't like to be edited, so how to you save manual changes?

Comment: remove static from string class. A top level class cannot be static ,  see my answer

Comment: As in, remove the word "static" from the first line in my example, "public static final class string {"? Well, I tried, but it unfortunately reverts the change, and doesn't fix anything.

Answer (score 3):

You named a field in your strings.xml called "Long Sword", change it to "Long_Sword", spaces aren't supported in the names.

Also, never ever touch the R.java file

Comment: I actually put the field in the strings.xml AFTER the error appeared :\ Here's the code:    
     <string name="Long_Sword">LeagueClicker</string> But it hasn't fixed the error.

Comment: Also, if I delete the field, only the "Long Sword" line is left in the R.java, like it's representing a ghost string! This line does indeed produce the syntax error.

Comment: Weird, try removing those strings in your strings.xml file and clean the project (project --> clean).  After that try putting the `long_sword` field back into the strings.xml file

Answer (score 0):

```
public static final int Long Sword=0x7f050002;
```

Is not a valid field name.

Naming Conventions: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove static from string class. A top level class cannot be static

```
public static final int Long Sword=0x7f050002; // not valid
```